# How to apply Javascript Highlight specific word function to a class or id

Tags: javascript, html

How to apply Javascript Highlight specific word function to a class or id

```js
function highlight(elem, keywords, caseSensitive = false, cls = 'highlight') {
 const flags = caseSensitive ? 'gi' : 'g';
 keywords.sort((a, b) => b.length - a.length);
 Array.from(elem.childNodes).forEach(child => {
 const keywordRegex = RegExp(keywords.join('|'), flags);
 if (child.nodeType !== 3) {
  highlight(child, keywords, caseSensitive, cls);
 } else if (keywordRegex.test(child.textContent)) {
  const frag = document.createDocumentFragment();
  let lastIdx = 0;
  child.textContent.replace(keywordRegex, (match, idx) => {
    const part = document.createTextNode(child.textContent.slice(lastIdx, idx));
    const highlighted = document.createElement('span');
    highlighted.textContent = match;
    highlighted.classList.add(cls);
    frag.appendChild(part);
    frag.appendChild(highlighted);
    lastIdx = idx + match.length;
  });
  const end = document.createTextNode(child.textContent.slice(lastIdx));
  frag.appendChild(end);
  child.parentNode.replaceChild(frag, child);
   }
  });
  }

  highlight(document.body, ['lorem', 'amet', 'autem']);
```

```css
.highlight {
 background: lightpink;
 }
```

```html
<div class="mytext"><p>Hello world lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing 
elit. Est vel accusantium 
totam, ipsum delectus et dignissimos mollitia!</p>
<p>
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Numquam, corporis.
<small>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Accusantium autem voluptas 
perferendis dolores ducimus velit error voluptatem, qui rerum modi? this is amet in the 
wall</small>
</p>

<div contenteditable="true">hello amet this</div>
  </div>
```

now this function applies to everything on the website, need to apply to class .mytext

I'm new to javascript so a demo example would be helpful.

thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

search the element you want first, and then use your highlight function.

example here:

```js
function highlight(elem, keywords, caseSensitive = false, cls = 'highlight') {
 const flags = caseSensitive ? 'gi' : 'g';
 keywords.sort((a, b) => b.length - a.length);
 Array.from(elem.childNodes).forEach(child => {
 const keywordRegex = RegExp(keywords.join('|'), flags);
 if (child.nodeType !== 3) {
  highlight(child, keywords, caseSensitive, cls);
 } else if (keywordRegex.test(child.textContent)) {
  const frag = document.createDocumentFragment();
  let lastIdx = 0;
  child.textContent.replace(keywordRegex, (match, idx) => {
    const part = document.createTextNode(child.textContent.slice(lastIdx, idx));
    const highlighted = document.createElement('span');
    highlighted.textContent = match;
    highlighted.classList.add(cls);
    frag.appendChild(part);
    frag.appendChild(highlighted);
    lastIdx = idx + match.length;
  });
  const end = document.createTextNode(child.textContent.slice(lastIdx));
  frag.appendChild(end);
  child.parentNode.replaceChild(frag, child);
   }
  });
  }
var byClass = document.getElementsByClassName('mytext')[0];

  highlight(byClass, ['lorem', 'amet', 'autem']);
```

```css
.highlight {
 background: lightpink;
 }
```

```html
<div class="mytext"><p>Hello world lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing 
elit. Est vel accusantium 
totam, ipsum delectus et dignissimos mollitia!</p>
<p>
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Numquam, corporis.
<small>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Accusantium autem voluptas 
perferendis dolores ducimus velit error voluptatem, qui rerum modi? this is amet in the 
wall</small>
</p>

<div contenteditable="true">hello amet this</div>
  </div>
```

Comment: the question is how? i need to apply this code only for class="mytext",  not the whole website

Comment: edited my comment with an example. you just need to search the element you want

Comment: Thank You so much, is working great

Comment: @IvanDern can you please mark it as an answer? it will be highly appreciated

Answer (score 1):

You apply your `highlight` function to `document.body`. Instead, you should apply it to element with id:

```js
highlight(document.getElementById('your_id'), ['lorem', 'amet', 'autem']);
```

Or to all elements with some class:

```js
document.querySelectorAll('.your_class').forEach(function(element) {
  highlight(element, ['lorem', 'amet', 'autem']);
});
```

Comment: thank you the highlight(document.getElementById works grate but the this function  is not document.querySelectorAll('.your_class').forEach(function(element) {
  highlight(element, ['lorem', 'amet', 'autem']);
});

Comment: I can't help you with that, you will have to figure it out yourself. The code is correct, it should select all elements with some class and apply your function `highlight` to each of them.

Comment: my bad,  is working correct both options, thank You so much